# Values are not set in HREF with javascript

Tags: javascript, href

library used : `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.15.2/URI.min.js"></script>`

I have  link and have two fields for which i am trying to set the value dynamically like the following,

```
// Get our <a> element
        link = document.getElementById('copyToNewWeek');

        // Use URI.js to work with the URI
        // http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/
        uri = URI(link.href);
        // Get the query string as an object
        qs = uri.query(true);

        // Change our value
        qs.selectedEventsForWeek = sessionIds.toString();
        qs.weekSelected = sessionDates[0];


       uri.query(qs);

       // Set our new HREF on the <a> element
       link.href = uri.toString();
```

but the value is not getting set to `href`

could some one help me please?

Comment: can you provide working sample on jsfiddle? anyway, do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: can you try with `setAttribute`?

Comment: it is not showing any errors :(

Comment: Bdw just `console.log(uri)` and see what you are getting?

Comment: what does `URI(link.href)` return?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes tried that too but it did not work, when i put alter(link.href) it shows the modified url but while submitting to server it becomes empty

Comment: @atmd it prints the url, at this time the query parameters has no value and  it prints that correctly

Comment: @Tony, check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywqeoqdm/): seems like your code work

Comment: To me here, the code you provided looks fine, so there is something we are missing. Can you please post all related code (html, js).

Comment: @Grundy it works fine for me too but not second time :(

Comment: what you mean `not second time`? can you modify this fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: i have two different pages and it works fine in first page and not in second page, only the ID value is different rest are same

Comment: do you cnahge id here `link = document.getElementById('copyToNewWeek');` to needed on page?

Comment: Yes Grundy, that is how

Comment: same code can't execute difference :-) try find where is difference, possibly here `qs.selectedEventsForWeek = sessionIds.toString();
        qs.weekSelected = sessionDates[0];` try check values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86586/discussion-between-grundy-and-tony).